# Written macro refers to have problems saving with value of cell VBA 2010 prfer not using any paswords if possible

Tags: excel, vba

I try to write this code due to copy a file from active workbook/create a new sheet/ copy the info on new sheet/ go back to copy the picture becouse it is not copying from the first time/ and save as the name of cel C71 of active workbook sheet (3) that is a date+ some text . What happens is that image refuse to copy, it wil not create the save as file + gives the original worksheet a distortion of image. In the code there is a problem in with selecting again the new sheet + saving with cel refs. Has anyboy a clue how to fix that please? As you see that is not a written code but registred. I would appriciate some help.

```
`ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-9
Range("A1:L71").Select
Selection.Copy
Workbooks.Add
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Range("A1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Range("A1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWindow.DisplayZeros = False
ActiveWindow.View = xlPageBreakPreview
ActiveSheet.VPageBreaks(1).DragOff Direction:=xlToRight, RegionIndex:=1
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=36
ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks(1).DragOff Direction:=xlDown, RegionIndex:=1
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(3).Activate
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 1")).Select
Selection.Copy
wbProcess.Sheets(1).Activate
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-48
Range("B2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementLeft 41
Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementTop -14
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-9
Range("C10").Select
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 1")).Select
Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementTop 8
Application.PrintCommunication = False
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .PrintTitleRows = ""
    .PrintTitleColumns = ""
End With
Application.PrintCommunication = True
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = ""
Application.PrintCommunication = False
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .LeftHeader = ""
    .CenterHeader = ""
    .RightHeader = ""
    .LeftFooter = ""
    .CenterFooter = "SAMANVATTING PER NIVEAU + TOTAAL"
    .RightFooter = ""
    .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.708661417322835)
    .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.708661417322835)
    .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.748031496062992)
    .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.748031496062992)
    .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.31496062992126)
    .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.31496062992126)
    .PrintHeadings = False
    .PrintGridlines = False
    .PrintComments = xlPrintNoComments
    .CenterHorizontally = False
    .CenterVertically = False
    .Orientation = xlPortrait
    .Draft = False
    .PaperSize = xlPaperA4
    .FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
    .Order = xlDownThenOver
    .BlackAndWhite = False
    .Zoom = 80
    .PrintErrors = xlPrintErrorsDisplayed
    .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False
    .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
    .ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter = True``
    .AlignMarginsHeaderFooter = True
    .EvenPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
    .EvenPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
    .EvenPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
    .EvenPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
    .EvenPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
    .EvenPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
End With
Application.PrintCommunication = True
ChDir _
    "C:\Users\Path"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "C:\Users\Path" & "OVERZICHT" & ("G71") & ."xls" _
    , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWindow.Close
```

End Sub

Comment: Does somewone feel free to give al little help please? I managed to let this code turn, but it is still not saving with "teks" and "date" reference that is marked in cel G71. I can not find how to copy also the picture when I select the whole page. It now saves with the name FALSE (excel 2010). If you like I will post the new code, but I think I just need some key features.. Thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the one who came to visit this post and had the same questions I would like to post that I found the solution myself and I am willing to share that with other people having the same problem.
I learned that it is important that you refer  te **Windows("Map1").Activate** if you would like to reopen the file in process, otherwise it is not copying the picture. Next important thing is that when you refer to save as a cel you have to be sure that you just enter 1 space between the & and other command to save. This one is perfectly working !

```
Range("A1:M71").Select
Selection.copy
Workbooks.Add
Range("A1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Range("A1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Range("A1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Windows("NAME FILE.xlsm").Activate
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 1")).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.copy
Windows("Map1").Activate
Range("B2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementLeft 37.2
Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementTop -6
Range("A1:M71").Select
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$M$71"
ActiveWindow.DisplayZeros = False
ActiveWindow.View = xlPageBreakPreview
ActiveSheet.VPageBreaks(1).DragOff Direction:=xlToRight, RegionIndex:=1
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=42
ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks(1).DragOff Direction:=xlDown, RegionIndex:=1
ActiveWindow.Zoom = 70
ActiveWindow.Zoom = 80
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-57
Application.PrintCommunication = False
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .PrintTitleRows = ""
    .PrintTitleColumns = ""
End With
Application.PrintCommunication = True
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$M$71"
Application.PrintCommunication = False
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .LeftHeader = ""
    .CenterHeader = ""
    .RightHeader = ""
    .LeftFooter = ""
    .CenterFooter = ""
    .RightFooter = ""
    .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.708661417322835)
    .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.708661417322835)
    .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.748031496062992)
    .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.748031496062992)
    .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.31496062992126)
    .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.31496062992126)
    .PrintHeadings = False
    .PrintGridlines = False
    .PrintComments = xlPrintNoComments
    .CenterHorizontally = False
    .CenterVertically = False
    .Orientation = xlPortrait
    .Draft = False
    .PaperSize = xlPaperA4
    .FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
    .Order = xlDownThenOver
    .BlackAndWhite = False
    .Zoom = 54
    .PrintErrors = xlPrintErrorsDisplayed
    .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False
    .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
    .ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter = True
    .AlignMarginsHeaderFooter = True
    .EvenPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
    .EvenPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
    .EvenPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
    .EvenPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
    .EvenPage.CenterFooter.Text = "TEXT"
    .EvenPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
End With
Application.PrintCommunication = True
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-9
ChDir _
    "C:\Users\Path"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "C:\Users\Path\" & Range("D2").Value & ".xlsx" _
    , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
End Sub
```